# why the icon on my statusbar cannot change in different mode?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, toggle, statusbar

I want to ask why the icon in my status bar does not change when the icon cliked,where as it should change in off mode when I click the icon.

```
<statusbar id="status-bar">
      <statusbarpanel id="inlinetrans-status-bar"
      context="inlinetransContextMenu"
      onclick="overlay.clickIcon(event)">
         <image id="inlinetransIcon" tooltip="inlinetrans versi 1.0" value="on" />
         <label value="inlinetrans" />
      </statusbarpanel>
   </statusbar>
```

this is the handler code of my statusbar

```
this.toggle = function(value){

     var icon = document.getElementById("inlinetransIcon");

     icon.setAttribute("value", value);

     this.status = "enable";

     if (icon.value == "on")
     {
         icon.value = "off";
         this.status = "disable";
      }
      else {

       icon.value = "on";
       this.status ="enable";

      }

     }
```

edited:

```
this.clickIcon = function(event){
      if (event.button == 0)
      {
        //left button is clicked.
       this.toggle(value);
      }
   }
```

thank you for your help..

Comment: As far as I know the icon is cached very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the answer of my question :

```
   this.clickIcon = function(event){
      if (event.button == 0)
      {
        //left button is clicked.
      var item = document.getElementById("inlinetrans-status-bar");
        if(item.getAttribute("status") == "enabled"){
          item.setAttribute("status", "disabled");
          item.setAttribute("image", "chrome://inlinetrans/skin/imagesOff.png");
      }
      else{
          item.setAttribute("status", "enabled");
          item.setAttribute("image", "chrome://inlinetrans/skin/imagesOn.png");
      }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your event handler is triggered?

The onclick handler calls the function "overlay.clickIcon(...)" while your javascript defines a method called "toggle".

Comment: yes it's true that onclick handler calls overlay.clickIcon,you can see it at my question above,i have edited..:) thamk you